# Python: changing values in nested lists

Tags: python, list

I am looking for beginner help with Python lists.
I create two identical lists a and b, but in different ways.
Then I try to alter one value in the lists, in the same way. Why am I getting different results for both lists?

**See code:**

```
a = [[0] * 3] * 4
b = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

print(a, id(a)) 
print(b, id(b))
print(a == b)

a[0][0] = 4
b[0][0] = 4

print(a, id(a))
print(b, id(b))
print(a == b)
```

**The result I want is done by:**

```
b[0][0] = 4
```

**but not by:**

```
a[0][0] = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @Roy2012 is completely correct.
I would add to their answer and say that there is a way of creating a "list of distinct lists" that avoids writing out the entire thing (like you did for `b`). Here it is:

```
a = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(4)]
```

This syntax `[x for x in range(y)]` is called a "list comprehension" and is the same as doing this:

```
a = []
for _ in range(4):
    c = []
    for _ in range(3):
        c.append(0)
    a.append(c)
```

Also note that there is an easier way of checking if 2 things are the same object in memory than using `id`. You can just use `is`. In the example in the OP, we can see `a[2] is a[3]` evaluates to `True` (so they have the same memory location) but `b[2] is b[3]` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 5):

The two lists you create are not identical, and that's why you're seeing different results.

```
a = [[0]*3]*4 # four copies of the same list
b = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] # four different lists, all 
                                      # three containing zeros. 


[id(x) for x in a]
[4953622320, 4953622320, 4953622320, 4953622320]
# note - all are the same instance. 

[id(x) for x in b]
[4953603920, 4953698624, 4953602240, 4953592848]
# note - all are the different instances 

b[0][0] = 4 # change just one list 
[[4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

a[0][0] = 4 # change one list, but since a contains four references
            # to this list it seems as if four lists were modified. 
[[4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
```

One final note - it's a cool question, in my mind. Takes a second to understand what's going on :)